# Como se puede hacer un PROGRESS BAR de segundos en ionic 3 y angular 5?

Tags: ionic, variables, angular5, setinterval

El principal problema es que no me muestra la variable dinamicamente de progressPercent del jugar-online.ts.

Hola mi problema es que no me muestra la variable en el html como va disminuyendo conforme tengo puesto un setInterval de 60 segundos... por lo que cada vez que pasa un segundo esta variable va decrementando uno en su valor.. y la variable que tengo si que me ejecuta bien como que va retrocediendo de 60 segundos a 0, y me muestra un alert como que ha terminado, la cosa es que no me muestra esta variable dinámicamente conforme va quitandole 1 a la variable...

Esta es la parte en la que llamo a la pagina en la que quiero que se valla y que me ejecute ese contador de cuenta atrás nada más darle click a ese botón de jugarOnline();

home.html

```
                   <ion-header>
          <ion-navbar>
            <ion-title text-center>Jugar</ion-title>
          </ion-navbar>
        </ion-header>

        <ion-content padding>
          <button ion-button full>
            <ion-icon ios="ios-add" md="md-add" (click)="jugarOnline();"> Partida Online</ion-icon>
          </button>
          <ion-content>
```

home.ts

```
      import { Component } from '@angular/core';
      import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
      import { JugarOnlinePage } from '../jugar-online/jugar-online';

      @Component({
        selector: 'page-home',
        templateUrl: 'home.html'
      })
      export class HomePage {

        constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

        }
        ionViewDidLoad() {
          console.log('ionViewDidLoad HomePage');
        }
        jugarOnline(){
          this.navCtrl.push(JugarOnlinePage);
        }
      }
```

Os dejo el codigo html y el ts para que me puedan echar una mano porfavor.

jugar-online.html

```
          <ion-header>

            <ion-navbar>
              <ion-title text-center>Jugar</ion-title>
            </ion-navbar>

          </ion-header>

          <ion-content padding>
            <div class="card">
              <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                <div class="loader">
                  <p class="percent">{{progressPercent}}segundos</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </ion-content>
```

jugar-online.ts

```
          import { Component } from '@angular/core';
          import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

          @IonicPage()
          @Component({
            selector: 'page-jugar-online',
            templateUrl: 'jugar-online.html',
          })
          export class JugarOnlinePage {
            progressPercent;
            constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
              var count = 60;
              var intervalo = setInterval(function () {
                console.log(count);
                count--;
                this.progressPercent = count;
                if (count == 0) {
                  clearInterval(intervalo);
                  alert("Se terminó");
                }
              }, 1000);
            }

            ionViewDidLoad() {
              console.log('ionViewDidLoad JugarOnlinePage');
            }

          }
```

Comment: OYE  progressPercent; Que es me imagino que es una especie de cuenta atras pero creo que no has definido una funcion   para ello. por que segun veo tu codigo lo tienen asi si mas  , no sta definida

Comment: Si está definida que cuando yo haga click en un boton me lleve a esa pagina de jugar-online.html y la cosa es que quiero que haga esa cuenta atras nada mas darle click a ese boton. Voy a adjuntar esa parte por si se ve necesaria verla.